What is the reason of using `%_pkgverify_level signature` in RPM macro instead of `%_pkgverify_level all`
What is the reason for using %_pkgverify_level signature in the RPM macro instead of %_pkgverify_level all?
The mitigation of CVE-2021-3445 is to set %_pkgverify_level all or %_pkgverify_level signature.
Some installation guides tell users to set %_pkgverify_level signature.
Some discussions say that %_pkgverify_level all is redundant.
When I verify an ISO, I need to verify the signature of the CHECKSUM, then use the checksum to verify the ISO.
For an RPM package why is it enough to only verify the signature but not verify the digest?
